# Should enums be considered as models?

Tags: oop, model-view-controller, enums, model

I'm in a state of a design dilemma wherein I'm unable to decide whether an enum should be considered as a part of models or not. The definition I have for models is that [they represent knowledge.](http://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/)

With that logic, an enum should be a model. Moreover, I have seen in some codebases that enums are stored as tables in the DB so that the knowledge is stored in the DB itself and can be accessed later for joins, or from code.

What do you guys usually do? For example, if you have a file called `models.py` which contains models, will you store the enums in it? Or will you create a new file `enums.py`?

Comment: I'm leaning a little bit towards a different file `enums.py` considering that if I just require loading enums in some other file, then I'll have to load the models too, if I put the enums in `models.py`

Answer (score 1):

ok under the assumption that models can be understood as classes:

If I design the namespaces and class-structures of a project I usually safe enumerations in separate files like "CarTypes.class", "Color.class" and put it in the same namespaces as the classes which will access those.
But that depends on the accessibility I have to grant other classes towards those enumerations. If only one class uses a enumeration or structure I will not put it in a separate file and rather will define the enum/struct inside the file of that particular class. But if it should be accessible over multiple classes or namespaces I definitely go for the first approach.
Hope that helped a bit. ^^